# How to display Season, Semester, and Cycle of years on Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm looking for a calendar that allow me schedule events for all semesters, weeks of semesters,cycle of years and seasons.

As suggested from the Github of Toast Ui, they said to look on full calendar TyperScript.
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6622

but the bot say to ask here so i'm here, there is some easy way to do what i'm trying to achieve, this is a project for a school so this is why i'm trying to get abstract calendar instead of normal calendar.

My goal is to do a Calendar to schedule event and then push to our LMS, our planing, but our staff use abstract date e.g(Semesters,Season,Cycle of Years) i asked to some devs and they put me on the direction of fullcalendar app coded in JavaScript, but when i display this i have this result.
[image: Screenshot]

```
           document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
              var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                headerToolbar: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'timeGridFourDay,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },
                views: {
                        timeGridFourDay: {
                        type: 'dayGridMonth',
                        duration: { week: 15 },
                        buttonText: 'Semeters',
                        weekNumbers: true       }
                    },
                initialDate: '2020-09-12',
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                nowIndicator: true,
                weekNumbers: true,
                
                weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
          
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true,
```

but when i try `day: 75` it only output me some weeks and not 75 days = 15 Week = 1 Semester

[image: day 75]

What i want is to display 15 Weeks but in this view type .
[image: View type but with 15 Weeks]

Comment: It's not clear what you want from us. Can you be more specific about what _exactly_ you're trying to implement, and what problem you've encountered when trying to do so? Give some examples please of what you want, and show your efforts so far including code. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my goal to be more specific, btw, in few works i wanna turn fullcalendar app in a abstract calendar (With view type like semesters, and cycle of years) but the view is not well displayed.

Comment: `when i try day: 75 it only output me some weeks `...how many weeks? Try to be specific, please. And I'm pretty sure it should be `days` not `day` (as per example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration). `week: 15` should also be `weeks: 15`

Comment: You definitely cannot make a 15-week view with the "month" view though, by definition it only displays one month at a time.

Comment: You might find the "timeline" view is more accomodating of your requirement, since it will automatically scroll horizontally, while the others do not. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view-no-resources . You can then customise the `duration` as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen an '`dayGrid`' view, wish allow me to view full weeks for 15Weeks thorught the similar month grid.